# Repository infrastructure throws StackOverflowError in SDG 1.9.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT when using Query Post Processing

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

When using the new [`QueryPostProcessor` feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories.queries.post-processing) and switching to SDG `1.9.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` from `1.9.10.RELEASE`, a `StackOverflowError` is thrown during *Spring* context initialization...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 155 more



Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.getSuperTypeInformation(TypeDiscoverer.java:465)
at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.getSuperTypeInformation(ClassTypeInformation.java:43)
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.getSuperTypeInformation(TypeDiscoverer.java:490)
at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.getSuperTypeInformation(ClassTypeInformation.java:43)
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.getSuperTypeInformation(TypeDiscoverer.java:490)
at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.getSuperTypeInformation(ClassTypeInformation.java:43)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
```

Comment: This StackTrace is hardly useful without your configuration and your application _Repository_ (`userRepository`) interface definition.  Please update your question with the necessary details.  Alternatively, you can share an example repo with me that is reproducing the problem and I can take a look.  Thanks!

Comment: Just figured out this is caused when I have a Component annotation to a custom PostProcessor. Apparently userRepository is the first Autowirable component - so just removing Component annotation from the new QueryPostProcessor is resolving this issue - but trying to find a way to register the postProcessor.

Comment: Let me respond to this in an "official" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a rather interesting result (i.e. `StackOverflowError`) and may possibly be a bug/issue with the *Spring Data Commons* `o.s.d.util.TypeDiscoverer`; I am not sure and I have not investigated yet (more on the `StackOverflowError` below).

In a nutshell, SDG uses the *Spring Data* (*Commons*) `TypeDiscover` class to "inspect" all beans (definitions) declared and registered in the *Spring* application context of the nature, and by way of the example...

```
@Component
class MyUserRepositoryQueryPostProcessor 
  implements QueryPostProcessor<UserRepository, String> {
    ...
}
```

Implementing the [`o.s.d.g.repository.query.QueryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/query/QueryPostProcessor.html) interface requires 2 bits of information: the interface type to which the `QueryPostProcessor` should be applied and the type of the query, which in SDG's case is a `java.lang.String` since OQL is expressed as a `String`, currently (though this could change in the future).

Here is one [example in the SDG test suite](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/query/QueryPostProcessorIntegrationTests.java#L189).

So the question is, how to effectively declare and register an application *Repository* interface `QueryPostProcessor` as bean definition in a *Spring* context?

In my integration test, I ["explicitly" registered](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/query/QueryPostProcessorIntegrationTests.java#L178-L186) [my `QueryPostProcessors`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/query/QueryPostProcessorIntegrationTests.java#L189-L226) as `@Bean` definitions in a *Spring* `@Configuration` class, whereas you are mostly like using *Spring's* classpath component scanning given the use of the *Spring* `@Component` stereotype annotation, which can be problematic in certain cases.

The discovery of the `QueryPostProcessors` in SDG is tied to the "parsing phase" of the *Repository* infrastructure.  The *Spring* container may not have "parsed" the bean definitions (based on the use `@Component` annotation) for your `QueryPostProcessors`.  You can usually adjust the parsing order by moving your bean definitions around in your config, for both XML and JavaConfig in fact, but it is usually better to be explicit about your configuration.

While classpath component scanning is convenient, it is less obvious when something goes wrong with the scanning, parsing, and registration process.

I need to think on this more and run some tests.

For now you can follow what I have done in my [integration test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/query/QueryPostProcessorIntegrationTests.java).

Hope this helps!

Regards,
John